# MongooseJS and reconnecting to Mongo

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

env:  Node 12.18.3, mongoose 5.10.0, Mongo 4.2.8 sharded cluster

After periods of network instability, occasionally my node/mongoose app doesn't seem to send queries to a specific db. I have mongoose's debug flag enabled and I don't see any queries in the log. It seems like they may just be getting buffered.

Here is a code snippet. I'm wondering if I'm missing something obvious in reconnecting?

```js
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var conn;
var connect = function () {
  const dburl = config.get('activity.db');
  const dbOptions =   {
        "native_parser": true,
        "poolSize": 10
      };
  
  conn = mongoose.createConnection(dburl, dbOptions);
};
connect();
conn.on('error', err => {
  console.log('Activity model mongoose connection error event caught:');
  console.log(err);
});

conn.on('disconnected', connect);
conn.on('timeout', function (e) {
  console.log('Activity model timeout event' + e);
});
```

I don't see any log lines for the error or disconnect or timeout events (although they may have happened, but my production logs wrap too quickly).

Comment: Unified topology not used? Turn that on.

Comment: Hi, I've added useUnifiedTopology now in our dev environment.  Everything seems to be running fine so we will start phasing it into production. I haven't found really good insight into what exactly this does for me that I don't already have? Could you elaborate on why you think it will help?

Comment: This is documented/answered on this site.